# android TabLayoutのindicatorを中央に固定する方法

Tags: android, android-layout

googleのニュースアプリのように、TabLayoutのindicatorを画面の中央に固定するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。デフォルトではindicatorがタブに合わせて動きますが、これを、indicatorは真ん中に固定されて、それに合わせてタブがスクロールするようにしたいです。

[ggoleのニュースアプリ１](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9MOx.png)
[[image: ggoleのニュースアプリ２[1]]

xmlの

```
   app:tabMode="scrollable"
   app:tabContentStart="72dp"
```

でそれっぽいことはできるのですが、これだと、ViewPagerに合わせてタブが最後までスクロールされるとタブのスクロールが止まり、代わりにindicatorが動き出してしまいます。（すみません、文章で説明しづらいです）解決策はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

`TabLayout`で実現するのは難しいように思います。

ライブラリの紹介になってしまいますが、こちらのライブラリの`Always In Center`を使えばご希望の動作を実現できそうです。
https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

[image: SmartTabLayout]

また、Google Newsstand風のレイアウトを利用したいのであればこちらのライブラリも便利です。
もちろんこちらもタブのcenter指定が可能です。
https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager